# Resultado vacío en file_get_contents

Tags: php

Estoy usando `file_get_contents` para ver unos datos de un enlace pero en el servidor ya de producción me da el resultado vació.

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input in
```

Pero en *localhost* funciona bien:

```
$enlace = file_get_contents($_POST["enlace"]);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
doc->loadHTML($enlace);
```

El error se da en la tercera línea, le hice un `var_dump($_POST["enlace"])` y sí, me muestra el enlace. El problema es cuando pasa por `file_get_contents`.

Comment: que veas la ruta no quiere decir que tengas acceso a ella.. podes comprobar eso?

Comment: Haz un vare_dump(file_get_contents($_POST["enlace"])) y si devuelve false es que hay un error al leer.

Comment: Lo que me resulta es string(0) "" , pero como dije, en localhost si funciona, me muestra la información. Si hago un var_dump antes de file_get_contents si me muestra el enlace, y si hago otro var_dump despues que pasa $enlace = file_get_contents($_POST["enlace"]); entonces ahi si sale vacio.

Answer (score 1):

Uno de los casos en los que sucede esto es cuando estas en producción y apuntas a un enlace que no lo está, por ejemplo a un archivo en tu localhost.

- Confirma que el enlace al que le haces el file_get_content carga en web y es accesible.
- Prueba con una url real y completa, no relativa.

A mi me funcionó, espero que resuelva tu caso.

Comment: Si carga en la web, es un enlace, ya la probé agregando la url directo, buscando encontré eso, tal vez sea eso, voy a revisar.                                                       A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to specify the filename. See the Supported Protocols and Wrappers for links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have, notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they may provide.

Comment: Si te da problemas prueba con curl en lugar de file_get_content, es una buena alternativa.

Comment: Bueno al final utilicé CURL y me funcionó ahora si esta mostrando los resultados, gracias por el detalle.

Comment: De nada, me alegro que te funcione.

Answer (score 1):

El servidor puede leer el enlace? hay algún firewall? 
te sugiero no usar file_get_contents para leer documentos via http, prefiere cURL http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php es más robusto y puedes controlar los errores.